# Angular - service inheritance

Tags: angularjs, inheritance

I am trying to come up with code that would to extend Angular $http service to create more business oriented services.

Here is my code:

Base service:

```
classes = angular.module("app", []);
classes.factory('baseService', function ($http, $q) {

    var apiUrl = "http://localhost/services/";

    // instantiate initial object
    var baseService = function () {
    };

    baseService.prototype.execute = function (webService, method, params) {
        params = typeof params !== "undefined" ? params : {};
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var response = $http({
            method: "post",
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify(params),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': "application/json"
            },
            url: apiUrl + webService + "/" + method
        });

        response.success(function (data) {
            deferred.resolve(data);
        });
        response.error(function (data) {
            alert('Error');
        });

        // Return the promise to the controller
        return deferred.promise;
    };

    return baseService;
});
```

Extended service:

```
home.factory("homeService", function (baseService) {
    // create our new custom object that reuse the original object constructor
    var homeService = function () {
        baseService.apply(this, arguments);
    };

    // reuse the original object prototype
    homeService.prototype = new baseService();
    return homeService;
});
```

Controller:

```
.....
homeService.prototype.execute("reports.asmx", "getWebReports").then(callback);
```

Everything works fine, but I want to have an internal function in my extended service to call it from controller. Plus I might have more than one function in the extended service.

Comment: I would really appreciate any code sample.

Comment: Sorry, but I just done see how I can use the provided example in place of my Extended service.